# Run shell script in code editor software like eclipse on windows but execute the written code on Linux VM?

Tags: linux, bash, virtualbox, eclipse, code

I have windows 10 installed in my laptop and I have created a Linux VM inside Virtual Box.

I always access my Linux VM via putty and from there I used to create and execute the bash scripts.

It would be great if I can execute the shell scripts from my windows machine via code editors like Eclipse which would be so user friendly. But I am not sure how to integrate the code editor software with Linux VM to do that. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I personally use a Jetbrains IDE which allows me to create virtual environments and reference scripts from network attached storage. In theory this would also work with a Linux server so long as the storage location is accessible over the network. Though I have only ever used Jetbrains' Pycharm IDE, they also have another IDE named IntelliJ which should have similar functions, but for shell scripts. Hope this helps.